# Calculate number of days between two given dates

Tags: php, date

Can anyone correct the error in my script to calculate the number of days between 2 dates. 
The dates have been input through a form, the variable info is as followed:

```
[departon] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => June [2] => 2011 )     
[returnon] => Array ( [0] => 31 [1] => June [2] => 2011 )
```

I have written the code to calculate these dates, but its not calculating the day, it just outputs 0.

```
<?php
$first_date = mktime(12, 0, 0, $_POST['departon'][1], $_POST['departon'][0], $_POST['departon'][2]); 
$second_date = mktime(12, 0, 0, $_POST['returnon'][1], $_POST['returnon'][0], $_POST['returnon'][2]);
$days = $second_date-$first_date;
echo floor($days/60/60/24) . " days"; 
?>
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that on Stack Overflow you don't need to put in stuff like 'Hello' and 'Thanks in Advance' and 'Help would be much appreciated'.  This isn't a forum, we just do Q&A here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy way:

```
$depart = strtotime(implode(' ', $_POST['departon']));
$return = strtotime(implode(' ', $_POST['returnon']));

$diff = floor(($return - $depart) / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Note: there's only 30 days in June.

Comment: This was the solution I was just about to post, but you beat me to it, @netcoder. Well done.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is by using datetimes.

Consider this:

```
var_dump(new DateTime('1 July 2007'));

$a = new DateTime('1 July 2007');
$b = new DateTime('1 June 2001');

var_dump($a->diff($b));
```

The var_dump will allow you to see the different kind of time you can extract from it.

```
object(DateInterval)[3]
  public 'y' => int 6
  public 'm' => int 1
  public 'd' => int 0
  public 'h' => int 0
  public 'i' => int 0
  public 's' => int 0
  public 'invert' => int 1
  public 'days' => int 2221
```

You can convert your array to a date time very easily by using

```
$date = new DateTime(join(" ",$array));
$date2 = new DateTime(join(" ",$array2));
$diff = $date->diff($date2);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [mktime documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) specifies a number for the month, so you'd need to convert 'June' to '6'.

Comment: Hi Lance, can you elaborate on that point a little more please? the fourth parameter is the month in: $_POST['departon'][1], ...... Is there any errors in my code? Or I am just missing the point here?

Comment: @novice, yes, I caught my mistake and modified my answer.  You seem to be giving mktime a month value of 'June' instead of the number 6.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you. Will have a go at converting, any more help would be very welcome.